# how to reorganize an array of object using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a way I can make A to B using lodash? Appreciated.

A - Original array looks like below.

```
[
      {
        "customerId": 5458122321,
        "customerName": "C1"
      },
      {
        "customerId": 5461321801,
        "customerName": "C1"
      },
      {
        "customerId": 5434315807,
        "customerName": "C2"
      }
    ]
```

B - and I want it to be something like below.

```
[
      {
        "customerId": [5461321801, 5458122321]
        "customerName": "C1"
      },
      {
        "customerId": [5434315807],
        "customerName": "C2"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: would you accept a pure javascript solution?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, Why not? Anyway _lodash_ is just a library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Pure* JS solution using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) functions:

```js
var A = [
        { "customerId": 5458122321, "customerName": "C1" }, { "customerId": 5461321801, "customerName": "C1" }, { "customerId": 5434315807, "customerName": "C2" }
    ],
    // accumulating an object "indexed" by 'customerName' attributes 
    // for grouping 'customers' by same name
    B = A.reduce(function (r, o) {
        (r[o.customerName])?
            r[o.customerName]["customerId"].push(o.customerId)
            : r[o.customerName] = {customerId: [o.customerId], customerName: o.customerName};

        return r;
    }, {}),
    
    // getting values from the object 'B'
    result = Object.keys(B).map(function(k){ return B[k]; });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That did it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: @Bill, added some explanation via comments

Answer (score 2):

Here's a lodash solution that makes use of [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to group the collection by their `customerName`, [map](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) to transform each grouped items and then use `map` again to get all `customerId` in a grouped collection.

```
var result = _(source)
  .groupBy('customerName')
  .map(function(group, name) {
    return {
      customerId: _.map(group, 'customerId'),
      customerName: name
    };
  }).value();
```

```js
var source = [
      {
        "customerId": 5458122321,
        "customerName": "C1"
      },
      {
        "customerId": 5461321801,
        "customerName": "C1"
      },
      {
        "customerId": 5434315807,
        "customerName": "C2"
      }
];

var result = _(source)
  .groupBy('customerName')
  .map(function(group, name) {
    return {
      customerId: _.map(group, 'customerId'),
      customerName: name
    };
  }).value();

console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

solution with `_.reduce`

```
var B = _.reduce(A, function(result, item) {
    var addedItem = _.find(result, {customerName: item.customerName});
    if (addedItem) {
        addedItem.customerId.push(item.customerId);
        return result;
    }
    item.customerId = [item.customerId];
    return _.concat(result, item);
}, []);
```